# How to find previous Location in android to measure how far I travel

Tags: android

How to get previous Location in Android? I am trying to make an app that will update a location every 30 seconds and I want to measure how much I travel by finding distance between previous location and current location. However, I was only able to get current location. Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   //This is for the UI
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    showData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showText);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

    start.setOnClickListener(globalListener);
    stop.setOnClickListener(globalListener);
   //This is for the Location
   locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10,10,this);
}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{

    distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
    meter = distance + meter;
    showData.setText(Double.toString(meter));
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why won't you store the current location and then after 30 seconds read this stored value.
By doing this you can subtract it from new value and get the result which you are looking for.

Define two variables

```
Location oldLocation;
Location newLocation;
```

And then you can do in a loop something like this:

```
oldLocation = newLocation;
newLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
//Here you can start calculating
```

Make sure you will set newLocation before entering the loop.

It is what you were looking for?

Comment: lastknownlocation will get updated as soon as the new location update is received by the system. It will also be updated by any other app requesting the location update not just his own. Thus in essence, the lastknownlocation could potentially be only a few seconds old (and not 30 seconds). Of course you can always check the time at which you got the location update to see if it is of interest.

Comment: Yes,thank you. this is what I am looking for. Do I need a loop? because I do like what you said on OnLocationChanged() method. It is working but I feel like the number I get are a bit off then it is supposed to be.

Comment: Well, if you use OnLocationChangedListener then you don't need to use the loop. You should try with it a little. If I helped don't forget to accept an answer, and also check my questions - maybe you will be able to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Android System keeps only stores the last location that it gets. It doesn't store any previous location. You'll have to implement that on your own. Every time you get a location update, save the location. The next time you request and get a new location, you will have the old location to compare it with.

Comment: It looks like the same thing what I wrote above

Comment: Yes, but your answer has the code snippet to go with it :). On a serious note, the problem with getLastKnownLocation is that if you didn't get any gps update in the last 30 seconds, last known location still returns a stale location. You'll have to be more careful with this. Using the onLocationChanged removes the need of loop altogether. Everytime the a new locationChanged update comes, the user can simple check the time diff between the saved and latest update and if diff < 30 sec, simply reject the location update. The next update at valid time (>30 sec) will now be set as old location.